# How to solve Ignoring response 429 in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scraper and I got this error:

```
2020-03-16 10:59:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-03-16 10:59:21 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-03-16 10:59:21 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2020-03-16 10:59:22 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/buy> from <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/>
2020-03-16 10:59:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/buy> (referer: None)
2020-03-16 10:59:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (429) <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/between-10001-20000/list-1> (referer: https://www.realestate.com.au/buy)
2020-03-16 10:59:34 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <429 https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/between-10001-20000/list-1>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-03-16 10:59:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (429) <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/between-1-10000/list-1> (referer: https://www.realestate.com.au/buy)
2020-03-16 10:59:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <429 https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/between-1-10000/list-1>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-03-16 10:59:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-03-16 10:59:38 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2396,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 23618,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/429': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 16, 8, 59, 38, 227721),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 2,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/429': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 16, 8, 59, 21, 721975)}
2020-03-16 10:59:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to open the link on my browser and it's working fine on Google Chrome and Mozilla fire fox
so I don't know what exactly the error.

PS: the same crawler was working recently

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code [429: Too many requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means that the server you are crawling is rate-limiting you.

Try to decrease the number of requests sent in parallel, and/or to introduce a delay between the requests.

Comment: I'm using `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` and the same

Comment: Is there a wait between  each request?

Comment: I have this :
`DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.5` and 
`RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True`